# Threads inside spring transaction - concurrent exception

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, transactions, spring-transactions

Can I use multiple threads inside Spring @Transactional
by this way?:

```
@Async
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Future<Result> chrgAndSaveLsk(RequestConfig reqConfig, Integer lsk) throws ErrorWhileChrg {
    ChrgServ chrgServ = ctx.getBean(ChrgServ.class);
    //Test threads
    Result res = chrgServ.chrgLsk(calc); <--here working threads!

...
```

ChrgServ:

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class ChrgServ {
//Threads invoking...
public Result chrgLsk(Calc calc) throws ErrorWhileChrg {
...
```

Now I just get next exception:

```
15:49:16.143 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] INFO  com.ric.bill.ChrgServ - ChangeID=1121
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.ric.bill.ChrgServ.chrgLsk(ChrgServ.java:235)
    at com.ric.bill.ChrgServThr.chrgAndSaveLsk(ChrgServThr.java:89)
    at com.ric.bill.ChrgServThr$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8f447d36.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
```

But when I remove threads (rewrite code non-thread) OR when I move @Transactional to the place after thread processing my app works well!

Why does it happens? What approach I should use for threads inside transaction?